# How to create Cart with quantity on Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I need to build cart to my app, but i dont know how to add to nested model to Cart because i need `<%= text_field_tag 'quantity' %>` to each product not a button.
Now a have this:

Cart.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end
```

Item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_and_belongs_to_many :carts
end
```

And table CartsItem

```
class CreateCartsItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :carts_items, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :cart_id
      t.integer :item_id
      add_column :carts_items, :quantity, :decimal
    end
  end
end
```

my form

```
<%= form_for @cart do |f| %>
<% @category.items.each do |item| %>
<ul class="categories-ul clear">
  <li>
    <div class="form-div">
      <div class="item-name left">
        <%= item.name %>
      </div>
      <div class="item-size left">
        <%= item.size %>
      </div>
      <div class="item-desc left">
        <%= item.description %>
      </div>
      <div class="item-price left">
        <%= item.price %>
      </div>
      <div class="item-price left">
        <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit "Create Order" %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

User add quantity to choosen product then click Create Order and selected Item and quantity Insert into CartsItem table how i can do this please help.

Comment: It is called [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) look this railscast after watching this rails cast you are able to built it yourself. It is good practice to learn something and implement yourself

Comment: show your controller's code of create method